# How to change default boolean value via submit button?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, boolean, submit

The user can choose of one of two submit buttons. If he clicks `<%= f.submit :conceal %>` how can the default value be made to change from false to true?

```
t.boolean  "conceal",           default: false
```

because right now if the user clicks the button - the default value remains false:

```html
[1] pry(main)> Valuation.find(9)
  Valuation Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "valuations".* FROM "valuations" WHERE "valuations"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 9]]
=> #<Valuation:0x007fdf26c736b8
 id: 9,
 conceal: false,
 user_id: 1,
 created_at: Thu, 23 Apr 2015 16:21:31 UTC +00:00,
 updated_at: Thu, 23 Apr 2015 16:21:31 UTC +00:00,
 likes: nil,
 name: "Conceal/Private/Hide">
```

This didn't work `<%= f.submit :conceal => true %>`.

```html
class ValuationsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_valuation, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :like]
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]

  def index
    if params[:tag]
      @valuations = Valuation.tagged_with(params[:tag])
    else
      @valuations = Valuation.order('RANDOM()')
    end
  end

  def show
    @valuation = Valuation.find(params[:id])
    @commentable = @valuation
    @comments = @commentable.comments
    @comment = Comment.new
  end

  def new
    @valuation = current_user.valuations.build
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @valuation = current_user.valuations.build(valuation_params)
    if @valuation.save
      track_activity @valuation
      redirect_to @valuation, notice: 'Value was successfully created'
    else
      @feed_items = []
      render 'pages/home'
  end
end

  def update
    if @valuation.update(valuation_params)
      track_activity @valuation
      redirect_to @valuation, notice: 'Value was successfully updated'
    else
      render action: 'edit'
  end
end

  def destroy
    @valuation.destroy
    redirect_to valuations_url
  end

  def like
    without_tracking do
      @valuation.increment!(:likes)
    end
    @valuation.create_activity :like
    flash[:success] = 'Thanks for sharing your Value!'
    redirect_to valuation_path(@valuation)
  end

private

    def without_tracking
      Valuation.public_activity_off
      yield if block_given?
      Valuation.public_activity_on
    end

    def set_valuation
      @valuation = Valuation.find(params[:id])
    end

    def correct_user
      @valuation = current_user.valuations.find_by(id: params[:id])
      redirect_to valuations_path, notice: "Not authorized to edit this valuation" if @valuation.nil?
    end

    def valuation_params
      params.require(:valuation).permit(:name, :conceal, :tag_list, :content, :commentable, :comment, :like)
    end
end
```

### UPDATE

```html
Started POST "/valuations" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-04-23 15:27:35 -0400
Processing by ValuationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Xd4ISNLZxjryLJfxvauWUANBzJthCNBzUwhtxseB/ird77mdYoKY/f9Skzb68lClaWOIUJXie9qC0jI1l+d98w==", "valuation"=>{"name"=>"PRIVATE AGAIN", "tag_list"=>""}, "commit"=>"conceal"}
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.7ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", 1]]
  [1m[35mHabit Load (0.2ms)[0m  SELECT "habits".* FROM "habits" WHERE "habits"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", 1]]
  [1m[36mHabit Load (0.2ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "habits".* FROM "habits"[0m
  [1m[35mActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Load (0.2ms)[0m  SELECT "tags".* FROM "tags" WHERE (LOWER(name) = LOWER('ingrain'))
  [1m[36m (0.1ms)[0m  [1mbegin transaction[0m
  [1m[35mSQL (31.7ms)[0m  INSERT INTO "valuations" ("name", "user_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["name", "PRIVATE AGAIN"], ["user_id", 1], ["created_at", "2015-04-23 19:27:36.015267"], ["updated_at", "2015-04-23 19:27:36.015267"]]
  [1m[36mActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "tags".* FROM "tags" INNER JOIN "taggings" ON "tags"."id" = "taggings"."tag_id" WHERE "taggings"."taggable_id" = ? AND "taggings"."taggable_type" = ? AND (taggings.context = 'tags' AND taggings.tagger_id IS NULL)[0m  [["taggable_id", 15], ["taggable_type", "Valuation"]]
  [1m[35m (10.8ms)[0m  commit transaction
  [1m[36m (0.1ms)[0m  [1mbegin transaction[0m
  [1m[35mSQL (1.7ms)[0m  INSERT INTO "activities" ("action", "trackable_id", "trackable_type", "user_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["action", "create"], ["trackable_id", 15], ["trackable_type", "Valuation"], ["user_id", 1], ["created_at", "2015-04-23 19:27:36.136688"], ["updated_at", "2015-04-23 19:27:36.136688"]]
  [1m[36m (1.5ms)[0m  [1mcommit transaction[0m
Redirected to http://0.0.0.0:3000/valuations/15
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `submit` method takes an argument for what name it will show up as, but that's only useful for determining which button, if there's more than one, was used to submit the form.

What you want to do is introduce a hidden field that has the right naming convention so you can use `update_attributes`, or you need to test for the presence of `params[:commit]` which, if present, means someone pressed that button:

```
if (params[:commit] == 'conceal')
  @valuation.conceal = true
end
```

Comment: Does that code snippet go in the controller valuation_params or the create/update action or in the _form?

Comment: @RubyonRailsBeginner That goes into your `update` action before the `@valuation` is saved, presumably where that button's form is linking to. As always, look in `log/development.log` to see what params you're receiving and what action was triggered. You may have it going the wrong way.

Comment: Not the create action too?

Comment: If you have two buttons like that during the creation step, yeah, that code will need to go there. It's only relevant in the `update` stage if you can change it after the fact, but in that case I think a checkbox is easier to understand.

Comment: Yea I can see the benefit of a checkbox I just wanted to save the user from additional clicks if possible. Here's what I'm trying:  `def create
    @valuation = current_user.valuations.build(valuation_params)
    if (params[:conceal].present?)
      @valuation.conceal = true
    end
    if @valuation.save
      track_activity @valuation
      redirect_to @valuation, notice: 'Value was successfully created'
    else
      @feed_items = []
      render 'pages/home'
  end`

Comment: Tried this too: `def create
    @valuation = current_user.valuations.build(valuation_params)
    if @valuation.save
      if (params[:conceal].present?)
        @valuation.conceal = true
      end
      track_activity @valuation
      redirect_to @valuation, notice: 'Value was successfully created'
    else
      @feed_items = []
      render 'pages/home'
    end
  end`

Comment: Okay third attempt and now I'm really stuck:   `def create
    @valuation = current_user.valuations.build(valuation_params)
    if (params[:conceal].present?)
      @valuation.conceal = true
      @valuation.save
      track_activity @valuation
      redirect_to @valuation, notice: 'Value was successfully created'
    else @valuation.save
      track_activity @valuation
      redirect_to @valuation, notice: 'Value was successfully created'
    elsif
      @feed_items = []
      render 'pages/home'
    end
  end`

Comment: When posting a lot of code like that, try amending your question with the new code. That makes it a lot easier to read. Did you see if the `conceal` parameter is actually passed in? It will show up in `log/development.log` if that button is working correctly.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see it there. I never used development.log before though so I could have overlooked. I just have this in views/valuations/_form.html.erb: <%= f.submit :conceal %> and its in the database and in valuations_params. How would you recommend I write it in the create action? You said the code is hard to read in the comments. Want me to update the question? This is what I found in development.log: `[1m[36m (0.8ms)[0m  [1mbegin transaction[0m
  [1m[35mValuation Load (0.2ms)[0m  SELECT  "valuations".* FROM "valuations" WHERE "valuations"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 15]]`

Comment: There is surely a lot more than that in there. Each request comes with a small header section that says what params came in.

Comment: Good call sorry I added the part above. I saw a line in their that said `"commit"=>"conceal"}`

Comment: Ah, then you need to check `if (params[:commit] == 'conceal')` instead. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Got it! Thanks so much for showing me the light with development.log too :) Keep being awesome!